# F2PY: Undefined reference to subroutine in module

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, f2py

I am trying to use f2py to generate a Python interface for my Fortran code. I wrote a test module and a subroutine to illustrate my problem.

**Contents of testmod.f90**

```
module testmod

implicit none
public 
contains

subroutine sub_in_mod()
    print *, "Printed from subroutine in module"
end subroutine

end module
```

**Contents of testsub.f90**

```
subroutine subroutine_py()
    use testmod
    call sub_in_mod()
end subroutine
```

The purpose is to call `subroutine_py()` from Python. As per the instructions I found online, I ran the following commands.

```
gfortran -c -fPIC testmod.f90 -o testmod.o
gfortran -c -fPIC testsub.f90 -o testsub.o
f2py -c testsub.f90 testmod.o testsub.o
```

But I got the error `testsub.f90:3: undefined reference to '__testmod_MOD_sub_in_mod'` in the last command.

Using `f2py -c testsub.f90 testmod.f90` resulted in successful build but that way did not work for my project because of complexity and custom types. So, I'd like to know how to tell f2py to use object files generated by gfortran. I found similar problems on stackoverflow but none directly addressed the problem.

**Edit**

According to the comment from Pierre de Buyl, I cleaned up the files and ran

```
gfortran -c -fPIC testmod.f90 -o testmod.o

f2py -c testsub.f90 testmod.o
```

which still results in an error.

Here is the full log.

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "untitled" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8\untitledmodule.c
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'testsub.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: untitled
                        Block: subroutine_py
In: :untitled:testsub.f90:subroutine_py
get_useparameters: no module testmod info used by subroutine_py
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "untitled"...
                Constructing wrapper function "subroutine_py"...
                  subroutine_py()
        Wrote C/API module "untitled" to file "C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8\untitledmodule.c"
  adding 'C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8' to include_dirs.
copying c:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8
copying c:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-8.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/mingw810/x86_64-810-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw810/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'untitled' extension
compiling C sources
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1\AppData
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt
creating C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8 -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt -IC:\Users\Thein Lin Aung\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include /TcC:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8\untitledmodule.c /FoC:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8\untitledmodule.obj
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8 -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt -IC:\Users\Thein Lin Aung\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include /TcC:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8\fortranobject.c /FoC:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8\fortranobject.obj
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
Fortran fix compiler: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O3 -funroll-loops
compile options: '-IC:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\src.win-amd64-3.8 -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -c'
Program:f90: testsub.f90
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared ..\..\..\..\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\testsub.o -LC:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0 -Lc:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs -Lc:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\PCbuild\amd64 -o C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\.libs\libtestsub.APU2XWIZSCE75AFY5M5MJDAHS5PXOMHM.gfortran-win_amd64.dll -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--output-def,C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\libtestsub.APU2XWIZSCE75AFY5M5MJDAHS5PXOMHM.gfortran-win_amd64.def -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -static -mlong-double-64
..\..\..\..\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\testsub.o: In function `subroutine_py_':
C:\Users\Thein Lin Aung\Downloads\drive-download-20200111T023258Z-001\f2pyTest/testsub.f90:3: undefined reference to `__testmod_MOD_sub_in_mod'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared ..\..\..\..\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\testsub.o -LC:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0 -Lc:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\libs -Lc:\users\thein lin aung\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\PCbuild\amd64 -o C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\.libs\libtestsub.APU2XWIZSCE75AFY5M5MJDAHS5PXOMHM.gfortran-win_amd64.dll -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--output-def,C:\Users\THEINL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1mpqikyt\Release\libtestsub.APU2XWIZSCE75AFY5M5MJDAHS5PXOMHM.gfortran-win_amd64.def -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-import -static -mlong-double-64" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Why do you compile testsub.f90 twice?

Comment: As Vladimir F mentions, testsub.f90 is compiled twice: once with `gfortran -c`, once with `f2py -c`. Remove your second line and replace the last by `f2py -c testsub.f90 testmod.o`.

Comment: I removed the second line and replaced the last by `f2py -c testsub.f90 testmod.o` but the error still exists.

Comment: Also clean up existing `.mod` and `.o` files then. If that does not work, make sure to include all steps and the full error log by editing the question.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have edited the question with the full log.